# how to get google place id in NsmutableArray swift?

Tags: swift, google-maps, nsmutablearray, mapkit

i want to extract the place id from google place API
here is the sample code

```
 for result in results! {
            if let result = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction {
                print("Result \(result.attributedFullText) with placeID \(result.placeID)")

                self.placeId.addObject(result.placeID)
                print("placeId==\(self.placeId)")

      //          self.placeId.addObject(result.placeID)
                 }               
//                 self.placeId.addObject(result.placeID)
 //                print("placeId==\(self.placeId)")
        }
```

while iam adding self.placeId.addObject(result.placeID) i getting crash

my result value in Nslog is

```
Result Restaurant{
GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x7b85acc0>";
}-A, Limpopo, South Africa{
} with placeID ChIJ91Ja9qr8wB4RJWDoiYanNIo
Result Restaurant{
GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x7b87d2e0>";
} Chayo, Mexico{
} with placeID ChIJP6GUHEmTvIYRc3CD5bAotiE
Result Restaurant{
GMSAutocompleteMatch = "<GMSAutocompleteMatchFragment: 0x7b87d990>";
}e, Mexico{
} with placeID ChIJrV4AvelmyIYR7-jos-aGxDY
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `result.attributedFullText.string` instead of `result.attributedFullText`